# Autofac is not loading module from Multi Target .Net Standard library

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, .net-standard

I'm developing a windows service and I'm referencing a .NET Standard library where I have an Autofac Module, I'm going call this library as `A`. I have the following `PropertyGroup` in the csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFrameworks>net461;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And this is the Autofac module quoted earlier:

```
 public class DefaultModule:Module
 {
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
 #if net461
        builder.Register(context => {
            return new BusSettings
            {
                HostAddress = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostAddress"],
                Username = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"],
                Password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"],
                QueueName=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QueueName"]
            };
        }).AsSelf();
 #else
        builder.Register(context => {
            var configuration = context.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
            return new BusSettings
            {
                HostAddress = configuration["BusSettings:HostAddress"],
                Username = configuration["BusSettings:Username"],
                Password = configuration["BusSettings:Password"],
                QueueName = configuration["BusSettings:QueueName"]
            };
        }).AsSelf();
#endif
```

Now I created .NET Framework console app using 4.61 as Target Framework.And this is the code I use to load the modules:

```
 //Library A is loaded By ExtractCustomAssemblyModules
 List<Assembly> assemblies = ExtractCustomAssemblyModules();
 containerBuilder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assemblies.ToArray());//Register custom modules
```

When I execute `containerBuilder.Build()` I'm not seeing Autofac loading the module and registering the services I have in my custom module, so is giving me an exception because it couldn't found a dependency. Now, I created a .NET Core 2 Console application and did exactly the same, at the time to call `containerBuilder.Build()` the code jump to the module and I see the services been registered and no exception this time

Why is not loading the Autofac Module in the .NET framework Console App?

PS: I found this [blog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jun/22/MultiTargeting-and-Porting-a-NET-Library-to-NET-Core-20) really useful, I  switched the first target framework to .NET 4.61 as you can see in the `PropertyGroup` but still I'm seeing in grey 4.61 code inside the if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Small Test

Lets build a sample library with

```
namespace MyClassLibrary
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public static string Info { get; } = "Conditionals"
#if net461
            + " net461"
#endif
#if NET461
            + " NET461"
#endif
#if NETCORE
            + " NETCORE"
#endif
#if NETSTANDARD
            + " NETSTANDARD"
#endif
#if NETSTANDARD2_0
            + " NETSTANDARD2_0"
#endif
            + "";
    }
}
```

and

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net461;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

If we reference this library in a .Net Framework 4.6.1+ console application with a simple

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp.NetCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( MyClassLibrary.Foo.Info );
        }
    }
}
```

the output is

```
Conditionals NET461
```

[github: Complete Solution](https://github.com/SirRufo/so/tree/master/50245414/MultiTargetLibrary)

### Conclusion

The directive `net461` is **unknown** but `NET461` is **known**.

As you can see, size does matters :o)

Comment: Thanks for your time sir. I think it was the combination of several factors, and this is was one of them. One thing I did that close and open the solution, when I did that one of the .NET Standard libraries was complaining because I forgot to reference System.Net.Http for the .NET Framework code. The weird think is this error never showed up when I wrote this post, maybe because I migrate the libraries from .NET Core to .NET standard. Anyway, after your change and doing what I explained before, started working. Thanks again